SQLAlchemy: Automatically update Column on Update
TL;DR: SQLAlchemy Column(server_onupdate=text('now()') does not trigger update.
I am defining a simple SQLAlchemy class:
class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("projects.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text("now()"))
    updated_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text("now()"), server_onupdate=text("now()"))

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("name", "project_id", name="unique_task_name_project_id"),)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Task {self.name}>"

I want updated_at to automatically update every time I change any values in that row.
I thought that the column server_onupdate would do that. When I run
UPDATE projects SET description = 'Explain duck typing to intern' WHERE id = 1;

I can see that this was successful, but the updated_at column is not updated. How do I fix my code?
Can I prevent anyone (but this trigger) from setting this column manually?

From the SQLAlchemy docs: "This [server_onupdate] construct does not actually implement any kind of generation function within the database, which instead must be specified separately." - Related question here.


Why are you converting to text for a  timestamp field? 2) What if you use server_onupdate=func.now()


@GordThompson thank you for the response. Do you know how I can achieve what I want using SQLAlchemy? Otherwise ill write a SQL script and run it at some point manually after creating the DB.

@AdrianKlaver AFAIK text("function_name()") is equivalent to func.function_name().

Then you are probably going to have to do something similar to Persistence: Notes on eagerly fetching client invoked SQL expressions used for INSERT or UPDATE. Along lines of ... onupdate=func.now() ... server_onupdate=FetchedValue(). Basically materialize the value then use it.
